# Integral of a connected simply connected Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose a connected simply connected Lie group $G$ has an integral $H$, so $G = H'$ (the commutator subgroup of $H$). Can $H$ always be chosen to be connected; that is, is there a connected Lie group $K$ such that $G = K'$?

Comment: What does the word "integral" mean in this case?

Comment: The 'integral' of G is simply another Lie group H such that G is the commutator subgroup of H.  Other terminology has been used, but this terminology has appeared in several papers.

Comment: This is term from general group theory and I understand that it is not ideal in the context of Lie groups.

Comment: Maybe that is why we should not use it in this context.

Comment: Other terminology is that G is called a C-group or commutator-realisable, but I don't know of another term for H.